# Get Token button in "Try it" doesn't give me a key in IE11

Tags: bug, documentation

When I visit for example the [timeline docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-timeline)  to try that api I need to get a token first by clicking 'Get Token'.

In IE11 (win 7/x64) this is broken. A window does pop-up but there is never a key returned in the input field.

On Chrome this works as expected.

Can this be fixed so it works for all supported browsers?